# Rsyslog log rotation using output channels

Tags: linux, ubuntu, rsyslog

I'm running rsyslogd 4.2.0 on Ubuntu. I'm trying to use the output channel feature described here: http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/rsyslog_conf_output.html

Here's the relevant portion of my config:

```
$outchannel test_rotated,/var/log/test/test.log,1000000,/root/scripts/rotate-test-logs.pl
local0.* :omfile:$test_rotated
```

But rsyslog refuses to do anything and the /var/log/test/test.log does not even appear.
If I replace those two lines with:

```
local0.* /var/log/test/test.log
```

everything works (but file is not rotated automatically of course).

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Ubuntu's man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man5/rsyslog.conf.5.html)<sup>**a**</sup> doesn't seem to suggest the syntax

```
local0.* :omfile:$test_rotated
```

the site you linked advises -- it says:

```
Keep  in  mind  that $outchannel just defines a channel with "name". It
does not activate it.  To do so, you must  use  a  selector  line  (see
below).  That selector line includes the channel name plus an $ sign in
front of it. A sample might be:

       *.* $mychannel
```

Maybe this works:

```
local0.* $test_rotated
```

**a**: It apparently depends on the version of `rsyslog` you use, hence on the Ubuntu release. It would thus be save to just look at *your* man page (`man rsyslog.conf`) or chose the right release in the site I linked.

Comment: That was indeed the problem, silly me. Thanks again.