# Logrotate or scripting to manipulate log file

Tags: scripting, cron, logrotate

I want to make sure that a certain log file gets empty when it reaches a specific size. I first used `logrotate` since the man page says:

> It will not modify a log multiple times in one day unless the criterium for that log is based on the log’s size.

However, it seems that the log file is only rotated when I force it using `logrotate -f /etc/logrotate.conf` or, the next day since `logrotate` is located at `/etc/cron.daily/logrotate`.

Here is my `logrotate.conf` file:

```
...
/var/log/maillog
{
    missingok
    notifempty
    nocompress
    size=10k
    postrotate
        touch /var/log/maillog
    endscript
}
```

I'd like to know your opinion on this. Is there something wrong with my config or should I use a script that always checks the log file size?

Comment: `logrotate` runs daily by default. You can change that to anything you want. However, it won't rotate a log the instant it hits a certain size - only then next time it runs.

Comment: @muru sorry. my config doesn't have the `=`

Comment: Yould consider using the `Out Channels` facility in `rsyslogd` (if that's what you are using) to automatically rotate the log when it gets to a certain size. There is another QA [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/33548/rsyslog-log-rotation-using-output-channels) on this.